# Why doesn't my dropdown submit the form?

Tags: javascript, .net, model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor

Here's my code:

```
<div class="center">
    <p>  Choose item:</p>
    <div class="dropdown">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Start", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "form", id = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedId, @Model.ViewJaren,
                new
                {
                    onchange = "this.parentNode.form.submit()"
                }
            )
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Been trying to get it to work but can't figure it out. I got the `onchange` to work with `document.getElementById("form")`. But there is no value passed. I get a blank page.

Comment: Why is there an `@` before `onchange`?

Comment: You aren't submitting the form *to* anything. There's no action to post it to, you set the action and controller to `null`

Comment: Well I edited the code taking your remarks into account still no progress. No clue why the @ is there. I've edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: No, you should take a look at my edit though.

Comment: `this.parentNode.form.submit()` makes no sense anyway. Should have just been `this.form.submit()` Does the select have a name?

Comment: Your form already has an ID, so why not be explicit?  Change the onchange to: onchange = "document.getElementById('form').submit()". If that does not work , then view the source of the page to make sure that the onchange event is being correctly added to the select element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not just separate it out.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#@Html.IdFor(x => x.SelectedId)').change(function(e){
      $(this).closest('form').submit();
   });
});
</script>
```